# Dynamic & static arrays - data structures

Tags: solidity

I am programming a card game for fun to learn solidity. I have noticed that there seems to be a lack of data structures to use apart from dynamic/static arrays & mappings.

For example I have

```
struct Character { 
    bool engaged;
    string name;
    string charType;
    uint dna;
    uint weaponCounter;
    uint armourCounter;
    uint battleCounter;
    uint16 level;
    CharacterStatistics charStats;  
    mapping (uint => WeaponStats) weapons;  
    mapping (uint => ArmourStats) armour;              
    mapping (uint => BattleStatistics) battleStats;  
}
/// @notice An array(vector) of Characters. 
Character[] public characters;

/// @notice Dictionaries that get the owners total characters & get a character owner from the characters id.
mapping (uint => address) public characterToOwner;
mapping (address => uint) public ownerCharacterCount;
```

I can build a data structure that is essentially a vector of characters and some mappings.

But what would be required to introduce a binary tree in solidity, or any other type of tree structure?

Answer (score 1):

You'd build a tree like in any other language. Just keep track of child nodes. Here's a simple tree that allows adding nodes but not deleting them:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract Tree {
    struct Node {
        bytes data;
        uint256 parent;
        uint256[] children;
    }

    Node[] nodes;

    function Tree() public {
        // root node
        nodes.push(Node("", 0, new uint256[](0)));
    }

    function appendChild(uint256 parentID, bytes data) public returns (uint256 newID) {
        newID = nodes.length;

        nodes.push(Node({
            data: data,
            parent: parentID,
            children: new uint256[](0)
        }));

        nodes[parentID].children.push(newID);

        return newID;
    }
}
```

(To support deletion, you might want to use a linked list for the children instead of a simple array.)